# C# WebSockets. Obs-netsocket. Invalid JSON payload

Tags: c#, json, json.net, obs

So. I really tried to find a solution to the problem myself, but I think it was overwhelming.
I am trying to send a WebSocket but it gets the same response every time.

I'm using **WebSocketSharp** and **Newtonsoft.Json**

My code in C#

```
sr = new StreamReader("./json1.json");
string output1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sr.ReadToEnd());
ws.Send(output1);
```

My .json \\ Ps. I'm more than sure that this json is good.

```
{

  "request-type": "StartStopRecording",
  "message-id": "1"

}
```

In console.

output1

```
"{\r\n  \"request-type\": \"StartStopRecording\"\r\n}"
```

json

```
{"error":"invalid JSON payload","status":"error"}
```

So right now i don't have any idea what's wrong.

Maybe I should use something other than **Newtonsoft.Json**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is with double serialization. When you read from file with [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=net-6.0), you are getting a string but when you serialize that with NewtonSoft, u double serialize the string.

I would recommend removing the serialization in your code and send the string you get from `sr.ReadToEnd` method.